# What is the meaning of drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi

Tags: android

I am really confused What is the significance  of drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and  drawable-xxhdpi of android drawable type under res and how to decide which  one of them sholud use?

Comment: the qualifiers for different pixel densities are explained here: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
nodpi   Resources for all densities. These are density-independent resources. The system does not scale resources tagged with this qualifier, regardless of the current screen's density.
tvdpi   Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately 213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it—providing mdpi and hdpi resources is sufficient for most apps and the system will scale them as appropriate. If you find it necessary to provide tvdpi resources, you should size them at a factor of 1.33*mdpi. For example, a 100px x 100px image for mdpi screens should be 133px x 133px for tvdpi.
```

So when you create `drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi` the phone appropriately takes the resources according to its pixel density.If nothing is specified it will take resources from `drawable`. For more details check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

these are image folders for different densities.

`hdpi`images for the Android Broad Screen set or Android Phones with the Higher resolution.

`ldpi` Lower images quality supported by the earlier sets of the android

`mdpi` for medium images support

`xhdi` devices with maximum resolution.

Answer (score 0):

These are used to put images of different resolutions to address devices' different screen sizes. For more information, check: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

These folders allow you to store multiple different quality versions of a picture so that faster phone can show a better quality picture while an older, slower phone still allows the app to run, albeit with lower quality pictures. It also depends heavily on the DPI of your phone which one it uses. If you want more information you can read up on it on [This website (developer.android)](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

Android categories device on two bases

- Resolution which xlarge,sw800dp etc. (Mainly for Layout folder)
- Base on the DPI which is main point to Image that is handle in **drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi**

**More Explanation**

My `HTC explorer` screen comes under small screen, but because of high density pixel per inch it take image from **drawable-hdpi**. `Samsung Tab` with 10 inch screen comes under large screen category but take images from **drawable-mdpi**.

Comment: i think you have forgot `Orientation` and `Aspect ratio`

Comment: Orientation does not affect any related to drawable and density.